# I want to add user as "guest user" to my google play developer account

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have uploaded android apps using my google play developer account abc@example.com, now I wanted give access to user xyz@example.com as guest user .means he can see data app stats, crash reports, or active installs pie chart, etc. but cannot able add new app or not able to add update of the app. Anyone have an idea how does do it?

or

anyone have an idea how can I access my android app stats information. does google api is useful for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Android Console does not offer any fine graining on what guest can do on the console. You may have to look into app tracking services like [App Annie](https://www.appannie.com/) which could provide statistic info without allowing the user to upload a new version to your app. Altough it would be impossible for another user to update a new version of your app without having access to your [developer certificate](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html).

Comment: do you have any idea how this app annie  is get these information ..is there any api available for access those info?

Comment: Sadly, Google does not offer any api for the Android Developer Console. I believe App Annie gets around it by using a web crawler which downloads manualy the CSV file on your console. You can find this file by pressing on the "Export to CSV format" link.